# Trying to use a Lambda Function and getting NAN

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I have an object named air_list and it contains the following in the first column:

```
['John_F_Kennedy_International_Airport', 'Charlotte_Douglas_International_Airport', 'OHare_International_Airport']
```

In the second and third columns, i have Lat and Long coordinates.

I have another object named cust_loc and it contains Lat, Lon, and names of airports, coordinates, distance between coordinates.  Now, I'm trying to use a Lambda Function to basically say, if the distance is less than 500 miles, the Condition is 'In', otherwise it's 'Out'

Here's the function that I am testing out.

```
for i in air_list:
    cust_loc.loc['Condition']=cust_loc.loc[cust_loc.Condition=='Out'][i].apply(lambda x: 'In' if x<=500 else 'Out')
```

The In flags seems to be fine, but all Out flags come in as NANs.  All coordinates and distances are float and Coordinate is an object.  Any idea what's wrong with my setup?

These are two Pandas Dataframes:

cust_loc.info()

```
 #   Column                                   Non-Null Count   Dtype  
---  ------                                   --------------   -----  
 0   Longitude                                150961 non-null  float64
 1   Latitude                                 150961 non-null  float64
 2   coor                                     150961 non-null  object 
 3   John_F_Kennedy_International_Airport     150961 non-null  float64
 4   Charlotte_Douglas_International_Airport  150961 non-null  float64
 5   OHare_International_Airport              150961 non-null  float64
 6   Tucson_International_Airport             150961 non-null  float64
 7   Candy_Kitchen_Ranch_Airport              150961 non-null  float64
 8   Canandaigua_Airport                      150961 non-null  float64
 9   Asheville_Regional_Airport               150961 non-null  float64
 10  Dallas_Love_Field_Airport                150961 non-null  float64
 11  Fly_Barts                                150961 non-null  float64
 12  Tampa_International_Airport              150961 non-null  float64
 13  Condition                                150961 non-null  object
```

air_list.info()

```
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------      --------------  -----  
 0   Place_Name  10 non-null     object 
 1   Latitude    10 non-null     float64
 2   Longitude   10 non-null     float64
 3   coor        10 non-null     object
```

Thanks.

Comment: What type of objects are these? It's hard to answer without knowing what sort of object we're dealing with. Is this a pandas dataframe?

Comment: It looks like you're using Pandas. Are you aware that columns in a DataFrame have data types associated with them? What do you expect to happen if you try to replace a numeric value with a string in-place?